# JSF lifcycle : Skip Validation and update model

Tags: jsf-2

I have a form with a lot of fields.
I need to know if there are errors or not. 
But the user could save data with errors if he wants.

I use JSF and I ask me if there is an easy way to skip validation.
For information, the form with all fields is wrapped in a composite.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip validation by adding attribute **immediate="true"** to **h:commandButton** or **h:commandLink**.

```
<h:form>
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.input}"/>
//other input fields
<h:commandButton action="#{someBean.invoke}" value="Go" immediate="true"/>
</h:form>
```

In this case navigation will occur even if there are validation errors.

Comment: yep, but I need to update my model with error and with immediate="true", the update model phase is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a validator(not a jsf validator), which would validate the data and add error if any into faces message, call this validator in action method.

I guess this would achieve your goal, but JSF own validaotrs used wont be of help.

Hope this helps !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finnally, I have done an overload of RequiredValidator (and others) and pass a parameter to each button [Save with error] and [Save]. If save button with error is clicked then my custom Validator skips the validation. Convertion error can be a problem. So all my fields in my managedBean are String.
If I expect an Integer I'v to write a custum validator also for that.

Little heavy but it works.